# Select the strings that only contain a specific letter

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = 1:5, v2 = c('A, A, A', 'A', 'S', 'A, S', 'P, P, A'))
```

in column `v2`, there are three letters (A, P, S), where they can appear in any combination, e.g. `"A, A", "A, P", "P, P, S", "A", "A, A, S, A"`, etc.

What I want to do is to detect the rows that only ontain the letter "A", no matter how many times it is repeated. In my sample df, desired anseer is : `TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE`.

thanks in advance.

Comment: another one: `grepl('([A-Z])([, ]+\\1)', df$v2)` this is agnostic to the letter so the last one also matches, but you can change `[A-Z]` to `[A]` to get your desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex you can do -

```
grepl('^(A,?\\s?)+$', df$v2)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the regex pattern `^A(?:,\s*A)*$`:

```r
df[grepl('^A(?:,\\s*A)*$', df$v2), ]

  v1      v2
1  1 A, A, A
2  2       A
```

**Data:**

```r
df <- data.frame(v1 = 1:5, v2 = c('A, A, A', 'A', 'S', 'A, S', 'P, P, A'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the values into vectors in a list, and then check that all values in that vector are equal to A. You can do that with this line

```
sapply(strsplit(df$v2, ", "), function(x) all(x=="A"))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```